# PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver and qualifier delimiter

Tags: spring, sorting, spring-mvc, pagination, spring-data

We had an issue when trying to transform the parameters for the pagination and the sorting of an HTTP Request into a *Pageable* object in Spring Data/Spring MVC. Some of our sort parameters had an underscore character and when sorting on them we were getting an error. In the logs, these parameters were trimmed at the underscore character.

We have discovered that the *org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver* was using the underscore as default value for the qualifier delimiters. Now, we wonder if it's safe to modify this default value because we don't know what this qualifier delimiter is used for, and what consequence this would have.

The documentation of *setQualifierDelimiter* in the class *PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver* mentions:

> ```
>   The delimiter to be used between the qualifier and the actual page number 
>   and size properties
> ```

So our questions: what is exactly the "qualifier delimiter" ? When is it used ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Searching into the documentation and code of Spring Data Web gave me the answer.

The qualifier delimiter is used in conjunction with the prefix. In the pageable arguments, it is the delimiter between the prefix and the page number argument, or between the prefix and the size argument. By default, the prefix is an empty string and, thus, the qualifier delimiter is not used. But, if you set the prefix, the qualifier delimiter will be used to parse the parameters of the http request.

Setting the prefix is useful if you have multiple tables with pagination in the same web page and these tables are updated via standard HTTP requests (not an AJAX query for each table separately). In that situation, the prefix allows to distinguish the http parameters for each table.

> setQualifierDelimiter(String qualifierDelimiter): 
>   the delimiter to be used between the qualifier and the actual page number and size properties.
>
> setPrefix(String prefix): 
>   configures a general prefix to be prepended to the page number and page size parameters.